# SPD 2013 Workflow doesnt start automatically on item creation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, workflow2013

I have a library in office 365 and a SPD 2013 task process approval workflow attached to it.When the workflow is started, new task is created in Workflow Task list.

There is another workflow attached to Workflow Task list which gets started when an item is created. But unfortunately,my workflow doesn't gets starts when new item is created.

But when I manually enters the new task in Workflow Task list then it gets started.
But when the item is automatically created in Workflow Task list it doesn't get started.

NOTE: I have tried using System Account and normal user too.But didn't get any success

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This post has a similar question here is the [Link](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142849/2013-workflows-do-not-start-works-fine-manually-but-does-not-trigger-on-chang)

Comment: Hi are you get the solution?

Comment: SP 2010 based workflow invoked automatically while item created using SP 2013 workflow

Answer (score 3):

Since item creation is from system i.e. sharepoint site it is not treating as new item. So workflow not started.

In doc library workflow, after task creation step try to start the workflow of task list.

Refer this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2014/08/19/fix-sharepoint-2013-workflow-recursion-prevention-part-1/

You need to have at least May 2014 CU for this to work.

Comment: thanks for replying but can I have the action name in SPD 2013 Workflow from which i can start the Workflow of Workflow task list.

Comment: Can you do the task creation step using app step.

Comment: Thanks monica, need one more help from you for this question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199117/provider-hosted-app-that-is-hosted-in-local-iis-websites-and-linked-to-sharepoin