# Workflow is not started automatically in SPD 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am trying to create List item using workflow it create the list item but issue is that other list item also one workflow this workflow is not started when i create the item throw workflow. But when i create the item manually that time it start automatically. I set the workflow start setting 
1.When created 
2.Manually.

Comment: Are you trying it using system account?

Comment: Yes i use System Account. It start workflow when i create item form List but not start when i create the list item using workflow.

Comment: well firstly workflows dont trigger automatically when current user is system account. Atleast that is what i have faced. There could be another reason. Check this link: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198985/spd-2013-workflow-doesnt-start-automatically-on-item-creation

Comment: Thanks for reply i try other account also but it not work.

Comment: Have you check this link http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198985/spd-2013-workflow-doesnt-start-automatically-on-item-creation