# provider hosted App that is hosted in local IIS websites and linked to SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app

How to develop a provider hosted App that is hosted in local IIS websites and linked to Office 365 / SharePoint Online?

can anybody provide me helpful links

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks