# SPD 2013 Workflow not starting automatically on Item Creation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have created 2 workflows, the first workflow (Which works perfectly)has been created for a document library in which an item is uploaded for approval and kicks off the approval workflow.

Within that workflow, I have added a task which adds the approved document to a secondary list which should then kick off the reminder workflow automatically on item creation within my second list.

The approved item does move to the second list however, it does not kick off the Reminder workflow in which I have created for this list.

The reminder workflow that I have created has 3 stages the first stage is a 1 Month Reminder, the second stage is a 2 week reminder and the final stage is a daily reminder.

I have included a screenshot of the Reminder Workflow that I have created if anyone has any ideas or solutions that would be great.

Thanks a bunch.

[image]

[image: Reminder Workflow]

Comment: Just to confirm, the Reminder Workflow is configured to automatically start on item creation?  Also, what happens when you try to start the Reminder Workflow manually - does it run as expected?

Comment: The workflow is configured to start automatically yes and when I start the workflow manually it runs as expected but due to requirements I've been given we need it to start automatically.

Comment: I have tried publishing the workflow with a different account rather than the system account and I have also tried using the App Step in the workflow and that also has not worked for me.

Comment: When a new item is created by the first workflow, does that item show any indication in the workflow history that the Reminder workflow has kicked off?  Are there any statuses (e.g. errors, completed, etc)?  Also, could you post a picture of the workflow summary screen from Designer (the page before the one you posted)?

Comment: When a new item is created by the workflow it is logged to the history saying the item has been created but it won't start the workflow process for the second list. No messages to state whether it has started or failed. Finally, I have uploaded an image of the workflow summary page.

Comment: Are u creating item with System account ? try to create an item with different account.

Comment: I think the System Account is trying to kick off the workflow but it wont allow it to seeing as it is the System Account. Have tried with a different user account now and will get back to you with the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the source below, because items created by workflow are created by the system account, they don't automatically trigger workflows (either on create or change).

You can run the following SharePoint Management shell script (on the SP server) to change this setting:

> stsadm.exe –o setproperty –propertyname declarativeworkflowautostartonemailenabled –propertyvalue yes

From [Workflows not starting automatically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142849/2013-workflows-do-not-start-works-fine-manually-but-does-not-trigger-on-chang)